# How to auto type password for SCP or SFTP to automate it?

Tags: centos, scp, expect

I have script where I put `scp` command to backup file to other server. But when it runs it asking to type password. Is there way to automate this? I am using CentOS 5.6. I have seen few guides they use `spawn` command when I use it, its saying `-bash: spawn: command not found`.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# connect via scp
spawn scp "user@example.com:/home/santhosh/file.dmp" /u01/dumps/file.dmp
#######################
expect {
-re ".*es.*o.*" {
exp_send "yes\r"
exp_continue
}
-re ".*sword.*" {
exp_send "PASSWORD\r"
}
}
interact
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have 'Expect' installed. In Linux distributions with 'yum', run (as root): `# yum install expect` Then make sure the path to expect is correct in your script by typing: `$ which expect`  /usr/bin/expect The path returned is to be put in the beginning of the script at #!/usr/bin/expect -f

Comment: it was already installed (expect-5.43.0-5.1.i386) and path was correct yet still not working, maybe i call script incorrectly it i do "bash <script name>"?

Comment: Works when i use chmod +x file.sh and run as  ./file.sh

Comment: Cool then, yeah #! is a general notation to execute as script under another interpreter/program and it needs the file to be executable unless the file is directly passed to the program as an argument to  execute the instructions in the file.

Comment: One more question can i use timestamp in filename somehow e.g. "date";

Comment: yes, its possible. declare a variable, assign the date value but in the string format to it and then use the stringified date variable.

Comment: /u01/dumps/file.dmp[exec date "+%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S"] -- append this to the filename

Answer (score 7):

Use key based authentication with empty passphrase. This will not ask for password.

Follow [these](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/) steps.

Comment: cant use key authentication because server i scp to is shared and they dont let me install it

Comment: Alright, so you do not have other option than using `expect`.

Comment: yes, but i found answer already thanks though

Comment: You don't need to install anything on the destination server - just copy over a file (...using scp itself). Use the `ssh-copy-id` command to copy the key file over - it simply creates a file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` with your public key. Everything should work automatically from there.

Answer (score 1):

If spawn is not working, you need to check your expect installation. Sending password can be automated like this...

```
spawn scp "user@example.com:/home/santhosh/file.dmp" /u01/dumps/file.dmp

expect {
"assword:" {
    send "MyPassword\r"
    # you can send remote commands here..
}
"yes/no)?" {
    send "yes\r"
    sleep 2
    exp_continue
}
timeout {
    puts "\nError: timed out.\n"
    exit
}
}
```